# Viewing Angle Effect On Spectral Reflectance Sentinel-2

Tags: sentinel-2, angles, reflectance, research

I am new to remote sensing and would like resources and literature explaining the effect of viewing angle on spectral reflectance for satellites. I have read the study by Moriya *et al* translated to English, "A STUDY ON THE EFFECTS OF VIEWING ANGLE VARIATION IN SUGARCANE RADIOMETRIC MEASURES". It demonstrates that observed spectral reflectance values vary with viewing angle from UAV's. Is this applicable to satellites or is the viewing angle typically small enough that there is no measurable difference?

For example, in the image below, will the observed spectral reflectance from a satellite such as sentinel-2 be impacted for reflectance values observed close to the maximum viewing angle?

[image]